# How to save sql queries in sql developer worksheet?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This might sound basic ,but I want to know .. when I connect to a schema I want to run a couple of queries, So I want to save those queries in the worksheet of sql developer itself.. How to save them so that the next time I open worksheet can see the list of queries I want to run?

Comment: You can save them as files in your hard disk. Try closing those query views and SQL-Developer will prompt you to save them (or not).

Comment: Or choose Save from the File menu, like... most other software? You can change the default location to save and open files in the preferences.

Comment: There is also sql history which is persistent between sql dev runs. It has filter box to limit the past history to manageable length.

Answer (score 4):

You can save them as reports:

View --> Reports --> User Defined Reports --> New Report