# How to store a query in Oracle(SQL DEVELOPER)

Tags: oracle, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to save my queries in oracle.Let's suppose I have write this query in the SQL DEVELOP

```
SELECT name
 FROM producer
```

(I have many queries).
Then, I want to get ONLY the result -display it  from each query in my netbeans.
Searching all over the internet about how to do this (youtube ,google ) but I didn't find something that can be done.
That's why I think if I save it query ,Then I will be able to display it in my netbeans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save sql queries in sql developer worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564764/how-to-save-sql-queries-in-sql-developer-worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

You can't save your queries in Oracle, only if you would create a stored procedure but that's probably not what you want.

But you can save the queries on your computer or even store it in the version control and then open it with SQL developer or NetBeans.

Comment: can I save it in the Netbeans projects,on the specific one?

Comment: Sure you can. SQL scripts are simple text files